# Create a hidden AAR library in Android

Tags: android, export, aar

I created the `aar` library in Android studio.
I see the code when I import it in another project.
I don't want this.
What should I do to prevent it from appearing? 
Do I need to edit it during compilation or in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps mentioned below

1. Copy library.pro file to your library project from this location:

   ```
   ...\android-sdk\tools\proguard\examples
   ```
2. Comment these lines when building from Android Studio, it should be probably kept/updated when building from the command line:

   ```
   -injars  in.jar
   -outjars out.jar
   -libraryjars  /lib/rt.jar
   ```
3. Update your library project `build.gradle` file to use `library.pro`:

   ```
   release {
     minifyEnabled true
     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'library.pro'
   }
   ```
4. Sync and build the project and it should generate an obfuscated AAR file now.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pIphkKfnkGpqbViv8oClUJoV3a4sRBlz

it still looks inside.